# Trying to create a table of objects ERROR:Error(50,57): PLS-00765: COLUMNS or TABLE is not allowed in this context

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I am attempting to create a table of objects where I am pulling the data from another table based on an inputted number. I get an error "Error(50,57): PLS-00765: COLUMNS or TABLE is not allowed in this context"

and also

"Error(66,16): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type"

This is after attempting to compile the function.

```
-----Testing OBJ creation and table creation----
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Cust_Bikes_OBJ AS OBJECT
(
            CustomerID NUMBER (38,0),
            BikeSerialNumber NUMBER (38,0)
);     

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Cust_Bikes_TBL AS TABLE OF Cust_Bikes_OBJ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  CUSTOMER_BIKES (Customer_ID IN NUMBER) RETURN TABLE IS

        CURSOR cust_bikes_cur IS
        SELECT serialnumber, customerid
        FROM TempBicycle
        WHERE customerid = Customer_ID;

        CustBikes Cust_Bikes_TBL;

    BEGIN
        CustBikes := Cust_Bikes_TBL();

        FOR bikes IN cust_bikes_cur LOOP
        CustBikes.extend; CustBikes(CustBikes.count) := Cust_Bikes_OBJ(bikes.serialnumber, bikes.customerid);
        END LOOP;

        RETURN CustBikes;
    END;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(Customer_Bikes);
```

I am expecting the function to return the created table of objects. 
I am able to create the obj and obj table but unable to get the function to compile.

Comment: A function can't `RETURN TABLE`. Probably what you want is `RETURN Cust_Bikes_TBL` - the specific table type you just created.

Comment: That worked thank you!